# Using HP SOA Systinet Java API to upload a WSDL file

Tags: java, api, wsdl

Does anybody have any idea of how this can be accomplished?

I can create wsdlArtifacts, businessServiceArtifacts, webServiceArtifacts, etc, but I can't upload a WSDL file, I would like to have the same behaviour of the Systinet interface, that is, the file is parsed and operations, endpoints, WSDL artifacts are automatically created. I don't want to have to parse the WSDL file to create those.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Disable the parsing policies associated to the WSDL artifact on systinet.